# Recursion with Char, int and so on

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm currently looking at a recursion problem where it asks the user for a value, and prints a pattern using a recursion algorithm. I've got the algorithm complete, and it works with ints, but how can I make it work with any other type as well, char's per say?

Here's my algorithm,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int str(int);
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter a value for the pattern";
    cin >> n;

    str(n);
 return 0;
}

int str(int n)
{   
    int x;
    if(n==0)
    return -1;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<"*";
    cout<<endl;
    x= str(n-1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<"*";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing length so you use `int` value. Now I don't understand why you want to send `char` value? What will you send, give an example.

Comment: I've edited my code above, it will ask user for a value and take it into the algorithm. I want the user to be able to enter any type of value, whether it be char, or int.

Comment: What's the point of `x`? You never access it

Comment: Still unclear! What if the user input value `a`? What output you are expecting then?

Comment: If user enters a char....What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recursion, the function must :

- call itself : ok
- return a computed value for which you hope it will finally reach a special point : current `str`does not

I think you want something like :

```
int str(int n)
{   
    int x;
    if(n==0)
    return -1;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<"*";
    cout<<endl;
    x= str(n-1);
    return x;
}
```

or more terse :

```
int str(int n)
{   
    if(n==0)
    return -1;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<"*";
    cout<<endl;
    return str(n-1);
}
```